# Vue.js won't update it's place to edit

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I've been having troubles with my new side-project. Saw Vue.js, thought it was cool and gave it a try.

**This is where I insert my new blog post:**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Title" v-model="header" name="title" type="text" value="">
```

**And this is where it should update:**

```
<div id="create_post" class="site-heading">
    <h1>New post</h1> 
    <hr class="small"> 
    <span class="subheading"></span>
</div>
```

**This is my javascript file:**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#create_post',
    data: {
        header: 'New post',
        subheader: '...'
    }
});
```

If i put input below the place it should update, it won't work but if the input comes first, then it works like a charm.

How should I continue?

Comment: Got it working, but it only updates if I lose the focus on this input ...
The whole thing needed to be in create_post div, not only the place I wanted to show input.

Answer (score 0):

This is hat you need:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    header: 'Post Title'  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="header" name="title" type="text" value="">
  <h1>{{ header }}</h1>
</div>
```

What you are doing wrong is that, your vue element is **create_post** and input is out of that element, so Vue can't recognise `v-model` on that

Answer (score 0):

I told that in my comment i posted, and v-model **has** to be without .lazy ending to make it update in real time.

So the whole thing has to be in div `#app` and model has to be like `v-model="header"`, not `v-model="header.lazy"`